# GNU Make on Windows cannot see some executables

Tags: makefile, 32bit-64bit

Part of my deployment is to run a target on a Makefile on Windows called "deploy" that runs, among other things, `taskkill.exe` and `psexec.exe`.  Both are in c:\windows\system32 which is in `%PATH%`.

When I try to make that target, I get a message that psexec can't be found.  Taskkill works as expected.

As a test, I tried to simply `dir c:\windows\system32\psexec.exe`, but from the makefile, I get a "File not found". In the same shell, however, I can run the same dir command and get a positive response.

Why can't make even see that the file exists, much less run it?

Here is an example Makefile target:

```
exetest:
    @echo ------------------------------
    -dir /b c:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe
    @echo ------------------------------
    -dir /b c:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe
```

and this is what happens in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\GitHub>make exetest
------------------------------
dir /b c:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe
File Not Found
make: [exetest] Error 1 (ignored)
------------------------------
dir /b c:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe
taskkill.exe

C:\Users\Owner\Documents\GitHub>dir /b c:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe
PsExec.exe

C:\Users\Owner\Documents\GitHub>dir /b c:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe
taskkill.exe
```

I'm running GNU Make 3.81 and Windows 7.

I've tried both `psexec` and `psexec64` - same behavior with both.

Comment: if make is a 32-bit program, it can't see 64-bit executables in system32. You need to use sysnative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `make`, not `psexec` or `psexec64`

All 32-bit processes are put under [file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

> whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`

It seems you're using a 32-bit `make` program. As a result it won't see PsExec.exe in `%windir%\System32`. The behavior is the same if you run the 32-bit shell with `%windir%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`, in which case `dir /b c:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe` will give you a file not found error

You must modify the path to `%windir%\Sysnative\PsExec.exe`.

Comment: I had no idea %windir%\Sysnative was a thing.  Thank you!

Comment: or you can change to 64-bit make