# GNU Make doesn't see Node

Tags: node.js, gnu-make

I installed Make using Chocolatey and want to launch some commands from Webstorm.
But when I run command like this:

```
storybook-start:
    npx start-storybook -p 6001
```

I see error:

```
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Though node command is visible from cmd. How to solve this?

Comment: If you type the `npx` command into your cmd shell prompt exactly the way you have it in your makefile, does it work or does it give you the same error?  Are you running `make` from that same cmd shell prompt, or are you running it some other way?

Comment: Npx command in usual shell works fine. I run make from Webstorm using its plugin, that should launch make executable from choco lib.  May be it's because make is 32bit and node is 64bit (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679699/gnu-make-on-windows-cannot-see-some-executables)